# SDK2: Wait Spinner object?

Tags: rally

Is there a busy spinner object that is available in SDK2 to indicate when the user should wait?

In SDK1, it was called like this:

```
var wait = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Wait(config)
```

I don't see the an equivalent object in the new documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We didn't make an equivalent component in SDK 2 because this functionality is built in to Ext.  From any Element you should be able to call [mask](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-mask)() and [unmask](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-unmask)().

```
myComponent.getEl().mask('Loading...');

//do some things

myComponent.getEl().unmask();
```

Comment: When I do this with a grid, it just grays it out-- I don't see the animation or the "Loading..." text that you see in the Rally grids.  How does one do that?

Comment: Which SDK version are you using?  2.0p5 should handle the mask pretty well.  It's possible that the Loading... animation is hidden from the current view (are there vertical or horizontal scrollbars?)